# PHP - Adding text values of multiple text box values to databases

Tags: php

Basically I want to add the following information to a single database field, (The txt-via-hn textboxes are house numbers, the txt-via are address details)

```
$vias =         $_POST['txt-via-hn2'].' '.$_POST['txt-via2'] 
        .' -> '.$_POST['txt-via-hn3'].' '.$_POST['txt-via3']
        .' -> '.$_POST['txt-via-hn4'].' '.$_POST['txt-via4']
        .' -> '.$_POST['txt-via-hn5'].' '.$_POST['txt-via5']
        .' -> '.$_POST['txt-via-hn6'].' '.$_POST['txt-via6']
        .' -> '.$_POST['txt-via-hn7'].' '.$_POST['txt-via7']
        .' -> '.$_POST['txt-via-hn8'].' '.$_POST['txt-via8']
        .' -> '.$_POST['txt-via-hn9'].' '.$_POST['txt-via9']
        .' -> '.$_POST['txt-via-hn10'].' '.$_POST['txt-via10'];
```

At the moment, for example, if I were to enter two vias the following would be added to the database field:

`HOUSENUMBER ADDRESS -> HOUSENUMBER ADDRESS ->   ->   ->   ->   ->   ->   ->`

What I want to happen is if the text box value is empty, to not include the empty spaces at the end. So if I was to enter just two vias, only the following would be added:

`HOUSENUMBER ADDRESS -> HOUSENUMBER ADDRESS`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them all to an array, run [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) on them to get rid of empty elements, then [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) them, like so:

```
$array = array();
foreach( range( 2, 10) as $i) {
    $array[] = $_POST['txt-via-hn' . $i] . ' ' . $_POST['txt-via' . $i];
}
$vias = implode( ' -> ', array_filter( array_map( 'trim', $array)));
```

You could even check for empty values in the loop, and omit the call to `array_filter()`, like so:

```
$array = array();
foreach( range( 2, 10) as $i) {
    if( !empty( $_POST['txt-via-hn' . $i]) && !empty( $_POST['txt-via' . $i])) 
        $array[] = $_POST['txt-via-hn' . $i] . ' ' . $_POST['txt-via' . $i];
}
$vias = implode( ' -> ', $array);
```

Note that both approaches will yield notices if you attempt to access an index within `$_POST` if it isn't defined. To rectify this, call `isset()` before you attempt to read from `$_POST` to make sure the key is set.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 2; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    if(strlen($_POST['txt-via2']))
        $array[] = $_POST['txt-via-hn'.$i] . ' ' .  $_POST['txt-via'.$i];
}

$vias = join("->", $array);
```